# How to draw pie like chart in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How can I draw the circular chart in image below in ios:

[[image: circular chart]

or any library for multiple color in circular progression bar?

Comment: you can use this lib -> https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it yourself you could either use Core Graphics or `CAShapeLayers`. In both cases you probably want to create a custom subclass of `UIView`; the implementation would be different for the 2 approaches.

If you're using Core Graphics you'd implement the `draw(_:)` function for your custom view type. In that function you'd create a series of `UIBezierPath` objects. You'd set the end cap style to rounded, set the desired line width, and create an arc for each path using `init(arcCenter center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, startAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat, clockwise: Bool)`, set a strokeColor using `UIColor.stroke()` to set the current stroke color, and then stroke that path. (A path is drawn all in one color, so you need to create multiple paths to draw in multiple colors.)

If you're using `CAShapeLayer` objects you'd create multiple shape layers, configure their stroke color and thickness, install them as sublayers of your custom view, Create `UIBezierPath` objects as above, and install the backing CGPath object from each `UIBezierPath` into a different shape layer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```swift
ZStack {
    Circle()
        .stroke(lineWidth: 20.0)
        .opacity(0.3)
        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    
    Circle()
        .trim(from: 0.0, to: 0.3)
        .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 20.0, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
}
```

[image: A gague with rounded ends]
I found it in [this article](https://www.simpleswiftguide.com/how-to-build-a-circular-progress-bar-in-swiftui/) after searching ["gague" on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=swiftui%20gauge%20view&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjVvsTK6rDyAhXcnnIEHeUdAz4Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=swiftui%20gauge%20view&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoFCAAQgAQ6BAgAEBg6BAgAEB5QrDRYg3JgznNoAnAAeACAAXeIAfcFkgEDNy4ymAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=z-EXYZWbAdy9ytMP5buM8AM&bih=851&biw=1476&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS916US916#imgrc=lEe_5kkk7zyMuM)

Answer (score -1):

I've found a couple of CocoaControls that might help you:

[CircleStatus](https://github.com/natalia-osa/CircleStatus)
This control will help you to achieve what you want in a few lines:

But I definitively use [CircleProgressView](https://github.com/CardinalNow/iOS-CircleProgressView)

Its storyboard-compatible, to achieve a multiple line effect you will need to put multiple views one behind the other and set Track Background Color to Clear Color ;)

Answer (score -1):

There is a great graphing library called Charts. It’s a cocoapod and really pretty easy to use. 
[Charts graphing library](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Charts)